# bundling virtual paths in areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

I want to create a style bundle with following virtual path (plugin framework):

```
"~/Areas/Domain.PluginTest.Wui/Bundles/PluginCss"
```

When I go to that path I get an error stating that the file doesn't exist.
The Static file handler is trying to find a file. How can I make this work with bundling?

```
System.Web.HttpException
Message:

File does not exist.
Stack trace:

at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String 
virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response) at 
System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String 
overrideVirtualPath) at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext 
context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.
HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, 
Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bundler is trying to find your path `~/Areas/Domain.PluginTest.Wui/Bundles/PluginCss`, which doesn't exist.  This is why we generally prefix bundle paths with `bundles`

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/Areas/Domain.PluginTest.Wui/Bundles/PluginCss")
       .Include());
```